# Access Channels in ANTLR 4 and Parse them separately

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I have included my comments in to a separate channel in ANTLR 4. In my case it is channel 2.

This is my lexer grammar.

```
COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(2) 
       ;
```

I want to access this channel 2 and do a parse on this channel to accumulate comments. So I included that as in parsing grammar as below:

```
comment
:COMMENT
;
```

In the program

```
        string s = " paring string"
        AntlrInputStream input = new AntlrInputStream(s);
        CSSLexer lexer = new CSSLexer(input); 
       
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer,2);
```

Then I want to do the parsing on the tokens

```
var xr = parser.comment().GetRuleContexts<CommentContext>();
```

because I want to get the information from the CommentContext object such as `Start.Column` etc.

EDIT:

This is the improved question

To be more specific, I want to get all the tokens in channel 2 and parse them using comment grammar to get all the comments to a list(`IReadOnly<CommentContext>`) so that I can iterate through each of these and access the information such as, start line, start column, end line end column, and the token text.

```
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer,2);
```

This is not giving me the tokens in channel 2. And another thing I discovered is until these tokens are passed as arguments to the parser construct `XParser parser = new XParser(tokens);`

Then only I can access the the tokens by calling `GetTokens()`.In the tokes I can see that there are comments identified as tokens and is in the channel 2. Even though `CommentTokenStrem` species the channel number as above. it contains all the tokens.

1. What is the reason of not able to access the tokens until the parser object is created using the tokens?
2. I want to get a `CommentTokenStrem` in channel 2 and pass the to the XParser object creation to parse these tokens using my `comment` grammar.
   What is the best way of doing this in ANTLR 4 API?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CommonTokenStream`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonTokenStream.html) internally tracks all tokens from any channel. The only thing you *won't* see when you call [`getTokens()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BufferedTokenStream.html#getTokens%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Set%29) is lexer rules where a `-> skip` action was executed (no token is even created for those rules).

You can look at the tokens on channel 2 by using the [`TokenStream.LT`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStream.html#LT%28int%29) and [`IntStream.consume`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#consume%28%29) methods.

**Java example**

```
CommonTokenStream cts = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource, 2);
List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
while (cts.LA(1) != EOF) {
    tokens.add(cts.LT(1));
    cts.consume();
}
```

**C# example:**

```
CommonTokenStream cts = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource, 2);
IList<IToken> tokens = new List<IToken>();
while (cts.La(1) != Eof)
{
    tokens.Add(cts.Lt(1));
    cts.Consume();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to get the Start line number and Start Column number which is provided. But I want to access the End line number and End Column number which in not available. How to achieve this.

Comment: @Diode you can either infer that information based on the start position of the following token, or calculate it from the end position of the token in the input stream along with the start position of each line of the input (you must calculate or track this separately).

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
 var allowedChannels = new[] { 2 }; // add more if you need to
 var tokensImInterestedIn = tokens.GetTokens().Where(token => allowedChannels.Contains(token.Channel) && token.Type != CSSLexer.Eof).ToArray();

 // if you're just interested in one particular channel
 var tokensImInterestedIn = tokens.GetTokens().Where(token => token.Channel == 2) && token.Type != CSSLexer.Eof).ToArray();
```

Comment: I want to get the tokens from channel 2 and parse it using some grammar. Parser expect an IToken stream. So, I was looking for a way to get IToken stream in channel 2. I will try this approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, remember that the `TokenIndex` property on the individual tokens, will refer to the index in the original `tokens` array, not the `tokensImInterestedIn` - so beware of out-of-range errors.

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR 4  C# :

```
       using Antlr4.Runtime;
       ...

       MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer (inputStream);
       var tokenstream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer, TokenConstants.HiddenChannel);
       IList<IToken> tokens = new List<IToken>();

       while (tokenstream.La(1) != TokenConstants.Eof)
       {                    
                            tokens.Add(tokenstream.Lt(1));
                            tokenstream.Consume();
       }
       foreach (IToken iToken in tokens)
       {
              Console.WriteLine(" Line : {0} Text : {1} ",
                                iToken.Line,
                                iToken.Text                  
                                );
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could put all the other tokens in another channel and use the default channel for your parser.

Of course this would not work if you have two parsers that expect tokens in separate channels.