# ANTLR lexer action pushing infos to parser?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am new to `ANTLR4` and would like to know the best way to push info from a lexer action to the parser.

I have the following:

```
LINE_DIRECTIVE: '#line' [ \t]+ INTEGER [ \t]+ STRING_LITERAL { System.out.println(getText()); skip(); }
          ;
```

Basically I would like to push the `getText()` to the parser.

Putting a parser-rule for the line-directive is not an option as such a line directive can happen everywhere...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Communication from lexer to parser is not possible in a way you want (if I understand you correctly).

What you could do is put your `LINE_DIRECTIVE` on another channel (and *not* `skip` the token!). There are the `DEFAULT` (or `DEFAULT_CHANNEL`) and `HIDDEN` channels, and you can introduce more of them <sup>1</sup>. The parser only reads tokens from the `DEFAULT` channel, but you can change that at runtime <sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-channel()

<sup>2</sup> [Access Channels in ANTLR 4 and Parse them separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606701/access-channels-in-antlr-4-and-parse-them-seperately)

Comment: Thank you!

Using the hidden channel is the perfect solution in my situation.