# ANTLR 4 - How to access hidden comment channel from custom listener?

Tags: java, antlr4

Writing a pretty-printer for legacy code in an older language. The plan is for me to learn parsing and unparsing before I write a translator to output C++. I kind of got thrown into the deep end with Java and ANTLR back in June, so I definitely have some knowledge gaps.

I've gotten to the point where I'm comfortable writing methods for my custom listener, and I want to be able to pretty-print the comments as well. My comments are on a separate hidden channel. Here are the grammar rules for the hidden tokens:

```
/* Comments and whitespace -- Nested comments are allowed, each is redirected to a specific channel */
COMMENT_1   :  '(*' (COMMENT_1|COMMENT_2|.)*? '*)'  -> channel(1)  ;
COMMENT_2   :  '{' (COMMENT_1|COMMENT_2|.)*? '}'    -> channel(1)  ;

NEWLINES    :  [\r\n]+                              -> channel(2)  ; 
WHITESPACE  :  [ \t]+                               -> skip        ;
```

I've been playing with the Cymbol CommentShifter example on p. 207 of The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference and I'm trying to figure out how to adapt it to my listener methods.

```
public void exitVarDecl(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
    Token semi = ctx.getStop();
    int i = semi.getTokenIndex();
    List<Token> cmtChannel = tokens.getHiddenTokensToRight(i, CymbolLexer.COMMENTS);
    if (cmtChannel != null) {
        Token cmt = cmtChannel.get(0);
        if (cmt != null) {
            String txt = cmt.getText().substring(2);
            String newCmt = "// " + txt.trim(); // printing comments in original format
            rewriter.insertAfter(ctx.stop, newCmt); // at end of line
            rewriter.replace(cmt, "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I adapted this example by using `exitEveryRule` rather than `exitVarDecl` and it worked for the Cymbol example but when I adapt it to my own listener I get a null pointer exception whether I use `exitEveryRule` or `exitSpecificThing`

I'm looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18636296/3788802) and it seems promising but I think **what I really need is an explanation of how the hidden channel data is stored and how to access it.** It took me months to really get listener methods and context in the parse tree.

It seems like `CommonTokenStream.LT()`, `CommonTokenStream.LA()`, and `consume()` are what I want to be using, but why is the example in that SO answer using completely different methods from the ANTLR book example? What should I know about the token index or token types?

I'd like to better understand the logic behind this.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, so I can't answer how AnTLR stores its data internally, but I can tell you how to access your hidden tokens. I have tested this on my computer using AnTLR v4.1 for C# .NET v4.5.2.

I have a rule that looks like this:

```
LineComment
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]*
        -> channel(1)
    ;
```

In my code, I am getting the entire raw token stream like this:

```
IList<IToken> lTokenList = cmnTokenStream.Get( 0, cmnTokenStream.Size );
```

To test, I printed the token list using the following loop:

```
foreach ( IToken iToken in lTokenList )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0}[{1}] : {2}",
        iToken.Channel,
        iToken.TokenIndex,
        iToken.Text );
}
```

Running on this code:

```
void Foo()
{
    // comment
    i = 5;
}
```

Yields the following output (for the sake of brevity, please assume I have a complete grammar that is also ignoring whitespace):

```
0[0] : void
0[1] : Foo
0[2] : (
0[3] : )
0[4] : {
1[5] : // comment
0[6] : i
0[7] : =
0[8] : 6
0[9] : ;
0[10] : }
```

You can see the channel index is `1` only for the single comment token. So you can use this loop to access **only** the comment tokens:

```
int lCommentCount = 0;
foreach ( IToken iToken in lTokenList )
{
    if ( iToken.Channel == 1 )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} : {1}",
            lCommentCount++,
            iToken.Text );
    }
}
```

Then you can do your whatever with those tokens. Also works if you have multiple streams, though I will caution against using more than 65,536 streams. AnTLR gave the following error when I tried to compile a grammar with a token rule redirect to stream index 65536:

```
Serialized ATN data element out of range.
```

So I guess they're only using a 16-bit unsigned integer to index the streams. Wierd.